# Array Constructor with IllegalArgumentException Constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, illegalargumentexception

For my constructor this is what I have done down below, and that’s the code of block I’ve written so far even though I’m pretty sure it’s wrong, so how can I write the constructor for this down below?
Thank you :)

For this constructor I have to initialise the grid with a given array, and if the array is of size zero in any dimension I have to throw an IllegalArgumentException. The constructor should also check whether the boarder of the cell is valid and if not, throw an IllegalArgumentException.

```
public class Grid {

private Cell[][] cells;

public Grid(Cell[][] cells) {

    if(cells == 0) {
   } throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height or Width value is less than or equal to zero");
```

Comment: Try `cells.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your constructor should receive the dimensions, not the cells themselves:

```
public Grid(int width, int height) {
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    cells = new Cell[width][height];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(cells != null && cells.length > 0) {        
     for(int i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
          if(cells[i] == null || cells[i].length == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width value is null or equal to zero"); 
          } 
     } 
} else {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height value is null or equal to zero"); 
}
```